# Check value of an xpath in if statement

Tags: selenium, robotframework

Hi i am trying to check if my table is sorted by using an IF statement i am attempting to use the value i get from an xpath as follows.

```
Check if sorted by alphabet
sleep   3s
${stuurman}=    Stuurman
${sorted}=    Get Text    xpath:/html/body/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[12]/td[2]
IF    ${sorted} == ${stuurman}
    Log To Console  "Sorted"
ELSE
    Log To Console  "Not sorted"
END
```

But i get the following error:No keyword with name 'Stuurman' found.
What am i doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to what Matthew King answered for the variable creation, there is another problem with your code:

The expression inside the `IF` is passed directly to the python interpreter, with the framework substituting any variables with their values. So

```
${sorted} == ${stuurman}
```

is evaluated as

```
Stuurman == the text from the UI
```

Now this in python is actually "the variable `Stuurman` should be equal to the variable `the text from the UI`", but there are no such variables, they haven't been defined for py; thus an exception will be raised.

There are two options to make it right; as both are strings, you can surround them with quotes, and when RF substitutes them with the values, it'll be a plain string comparison:

```
"${sorted}" == "${stuurman}"     
# will be evaluated as:
# "Stuurman" == "the text from the UI"
```

The other option is to use the advanced variable syntax (I *think* this was the name in the RF user guide) and pass not the values, but the variables themselves. This is done by omitting the curly brackets, prefix a var just by the dollar sign.

Thus no substitution will take place, Python will get actual variables and will compare them:

```
$sorted == $stuurman
```

Answer (score 1):

When you're setting a variable within a keyword you would need to use something like "Set Variable" followed by the value. (A keyword is expected on the right side)

e.g.

```
${stuurman}=  Set Variable   Stuurman
```

You can omit a keyword when setting the variable within *** Variables *** section e.g.

```
*** Variables ***
${stuurman}=   Stuurman
```